# How to 'unpack' pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([['id','Date','Pers', 'Comb'],
                ['Row1','12-12-2016', 'John', [{"name":"asr","value":"no"},{"name":"flt","value":"641"},{"name":"dest","value":"lax"}]],
                ['Row2','24-12-2016', 'Pete', [{"name":"asr","value":"yes"},{"name":"flt","value":"751"},{"name":"dest","value":"nbo"}]],
                ['Row2','25-12-2016', 'Sue', [{"name":"asr","value":"no"},{"name":"flt","value":"810"},{"name":"dest","value":"tyo"}]]])
df_org = (pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:]))
df_org

        Date        Pers    Comb
Row1    12-12-2016  John    [{u'name': u'asr', u'value': u'no'}, {u'name':...
Row2    24-12-2016  Pete    [{u'name': u'asr', u'value': u'yes'}, {u'name'...
Row2    25-12-2016  Sue [{u'name': u'asr', u'value': u'no'}, {u'name':...
```

I try to extract the name-values from the Comb column and make each name also a new column. Like this:

```
data = np.array([['id','Date','Pers', 'asr', 'flt', 'dest'],
                ['Row1','12-12-2016', 'John', "no", "641", "lax"],
                ['Row2','24-12-2016', 'Pete', "yes","751","nbo"],
                ['Row2','25-12-2016', 'Sue', "no","810","tyo"]])
df_new = (pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:]))
df_new

        Date        Pers    asr flt dest
Row1    12-12-2016  John    no  641 lax
Row2    24-12-2016  Pete    yes 751 nbo
Row2    25-12-2016  Sue no  810 tyo
```

I tried via 'unpacking' the Comb column:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    rowdf = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(df.iloc[i]['Comb']))
    print rowdf['name'], rowdf['value']
```

But then I don't know how to append a new dataframe to the original rows.

Please help to go from df_org to df_new ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Using your dummy data, you can do the following:

```
def iterate(values):
    return pd.Series({x["name"]: x["value"] for x in values})

pd.concat([df_org, df_org.pop("Comb").apply(iterate)], axis=1)

        Date        Pers    asr     dest    flt
Row1    12-12-2016  John    no      lax     641
Row2    24-12-2016  Pete    yes     nbo     751
Row2    25-12-2016  Sue     no      tyo     810
```

- The helper function `iterate` extracts the values from the dictionaries while returning them as a pandas Series.
- When using `apply` with a function that returns Series objects, the result will be casted to a pandas DataFrame.
- `pop` returns the given column and removes it from the dataframe.
- `concat` finally merges your source df (without the `comb` column) and the extracted values from `Comb`

#### Edit Json Data

In case you have json strings in your `comb` column, you can convert them into regular python objects via `json.loads`. Simply change the `iterate` function to:

```
import json

def iterate(values):
    return pd.Series({x["name"]: x["value"] for x in json.loads(values)})
```

Comment: Thank you ! This run great with the dummy data. However on my data I get an error message:     
return pd.Series({x["name"]: x["value"] for x in values})
TypeError: string indices must be integers
I assume the data in the column should be interpreted as JSON but how should I do that ?

Comment: @ArtDijk Updated the answer.